# How do I clone a github project to run locally?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to follow this railscast tutorial for authlogic - and it points to the source [here](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-160/blog/) -

I have git installed - how do I replicate the source onto my localhost so that I can follow the tutorial like in the screencast?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
git clone git://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git
```

Comment: If you want to clone a particular branch instead: `git clone git://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git -b branch_name`

Comment: strange that there are dozens of obscure icons and links and options on GitHub but not a single bit explaining how to do a clone

Comment: Your one-liner command works smoothly with [core git](http://msysgit.github.io/) whereas [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) can't seem to manage authentication (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6138493/1864054) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15584516/1864054)).

Answer (score 23):

To clone a repository and place it in a specified directory use "git clone [url] [directory]". For example

```
git clone https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git Rails
```

will create a directory named "Rails" and place it in the new directory. Click [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) for more information.

Comment: // , This is a better habit to adopt, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You clone a repository with git clone [url]. Like so,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
```

Answer (score 0):

I use @Thiho answer but i get this error:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command

For solving that i use this steps:

I add the following paths to PATH:

- C:\Program Files\Git\bin\
- C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\

**In windows 7:**

1. Right-click "Computer" on the Desktop or Start Menu.
2. Select "Properties".
3. On the very far left, click the "Advanced system settings" link.
4. Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
5. Double-click the "Path" entry under "System variables".
6. At the end of "Variable value", insert a ; if there is not already
   one, and then C:\Program Files\Git\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd.
   Do not put a space between ; and the entry.

Finally close and re-open your console.