# Why does nothing happen when I click fork on github?

Tags: github

I created a repository in github and then issued the following command on my local box:

```
git push origin master
```

Now I see all of the files on github.

I would like to start work on making changes. With this in mind I clicked the fork button on the
github screen. However nothing happens. I see a message at the bottom of my browser screen but 
that's all.

How do I copy my "forked" version to my local computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work on your GitHub repo, you need to [clone it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872113/how-do-i-clone-a-github-project-to-run-locally).

- If you want others to contribute directly in your repo, you need to [declare them as collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator).
  You could set up a dedicated branch for them to use.
- If you don't want them to push *directly* to your repo, *then* your colleagues need to fork your repo, and clone their fork locally.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your repository, there's no need to fork the repo.

If I read your question correctly, to make changes, simply edit the files in question in a text editor, save them, open terminal, change directory to the one with the code, and write `git add .` then `git commit -m "Your commit message"` and then `git push`. The new code should be updated in GitHub as a new commit.

Comment: I have two others who would like to work on this project so what I was thinking was that I would like to make a different version of the repo with some files missing and make that available to the others. Is this what I would use fork for normally. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the only problem being if they wanted the missing files, they could just look at them in your repo. If others seeing the files is a security threat, you should not allow them into the rpeo in the first place.