# Can't manage to load my private key with git extension

Tags: git, git-extensions

I've been trying for the last 2 hours.
I'm using xp-dev as a git repository provider (because I'm already paying and I have svn repo over there)
I've given xp-dev my public key.

But when cloning my repo I a being rejected.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" clone -v --recurse-submodules --progress "ssh://xp-dev.com/repogit" "c:/ProjetPerso/repogit"
Cloning into 'c:/ProjetPerso/repogit'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Done
```

And from what I understood from various blogs, git extension should ask me to load my private key, except it doesn't.

I tried launching the putty authentification client (even though I choose openSSH) and loaded my private key inside, but it changes nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be prompted if your key is in the right place which on windows is I think _ssh/id_xxx in your user's home dir - where is your private key currently? Is that the output from git-extensions or you directly on the command line?

Comment: oh I didn't know there was a place to put your private key. it's from git extension. trying your solution

Comment: So none of this worked. in the end I uninstalled everything, reinstalled with putty instead of openSSH. and now I have a "load private kay" button and everything works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GitExtension ask to load private key only if you use Putty. You should do it manually for OpenSSH like described for GitHub https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 28):

I had this issue because I generated a SSH key with ssh-keygen and tried to use it with GitExtensions which only understands OpenSSH keys.

What you have to do is, from GitExtensions:

- Tools > Putty > Generate or import key (A new window opens)
- Conversions > Import key
- Import your private key
- Save private key
- Type a file name like `mykey.ppk`

You should now able to use this new .ppk file in GitExtensions!

Comment: This didn't work for my private key from github. (it was a file without any file extention I converted it to `ppk`.). When I tested connection it gave me the following: `FATAL ERROR: Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha2
56@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521)`

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty easy to do this with Git-Extensions;

1. Open Git Gui
2. Help > Show SSH key
3. Generate Key
4. Copy To Clipboard
5. Paste it into your profile SSH Keys in GitHub, Bitbucket, etc

[image: Git Extensions - SSH Key Generation]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue now. I was able to get the solution via the following link from GitExtension itself.

[PuTTy and Github](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_feature.html#putty-and-github)

Same would also work of GitLab. You will need to add generated ppk file to GitHub or GitLab under settings page.