# Problems accessing git repository

Tags: git, ssh

1. I created a 'New Project' through GitLab.
2. I verified that "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/test.git" exists, I even chmod'ed it to 777
3. I logged in via ssh manually (git@*****.net) and it worked fine, I could access the repository files from my home computer via ssh.

But when I do this from my home computer:

```
         git remote add origin git@*******.net:root/test.git 
         fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)
```

I have added my SSH certificate through GitLab as well.

When I try to clone the project, I get the same error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>git clone git@*******.net:root/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
git@d*******.net's password:
fatal: 'root/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

test.git:

```
 drwxrwx--- 7 git git 4096 Jan 28 15:55 ./
 drwxrwx--- 8 git git 4096 Jan 28 19:00 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 git git   66 Jan 28 15:15 config*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 git git   73 Jan 28 15:15 description*
 drwxrwxr-x 7 git git 4096 Jan 28 15:56 .git/
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 git git   23 Jan 28 15:15 HEAD*
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 git git   47 Jan 28 15:15 hooks 
 drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4096 Jan 28 15:15 info/
 drwxrwxrwx 4 git git 4096 Jan 28 15:15 objects/
 drwxrwxrwx 4 git git 4096 Jan 28 15:15 refs/
```

Comment: you should git clone the project first, then you can add remotes

Comment: could you post the content of root/test.git ?

Comment: try with git clone git://github.com/yourGitUsername/test.git

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is probably caused by repository not being inited. The easiest way, if you're working with [github](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh), is to clone the project you've created at 1. Also see [How do I clone a github project to run locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872113/how-do-i-clone-a-github-project-to-run-locally)

Then you'll be able to configure remotes and push specs.

```
 git clone git://github.com/yourgithubusername/test.git
```

Comment: the clone URL should be in format git clone ssh://git@github.com/authorName/ProjectName.git

Comment: unfortunetelly I have not. I have tried all possible 'paths' when I imported. weirdly I can login via ssh as 'git' user just fine, but not through git.