# No Github option on Android Sutdio when Checkout project from Version Control

Tags: github

I'm trying to modify an app from Github but there's the option's missing on *Checkout project from Version Control*. How to add Github in the list?

[Github option missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFYjU.png)

Edit: I don't see the link between my request and *How do I clone a github project to run locally?*

Comment: just clone it and open it on your machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a github project to run locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872113/how-do-i-clone-a-github-project-to-run-locally)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio but I imagine you should be able to select Git and then enter the URL of the GitHub project?

Comment: I can open it selecting Git but i think it doesn't work properly then. On all tutos the option is proposed. i.e: https://ibb.co/6FWZgpX